# Get all variables of the current function() scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prototype, instance

I'm having a problem. I want to get the current function scrope. I have this example code that i'm working ok.

```
function nittle(){

    var Pen = new Dot(); // Generated dynamical through eval()
    .....

    for(key in window) {
        if( window[key] instanceof Dot ){
            alert("found it");
        }
    }

}
```

But it seems not to work within the function scope. Work outside of it. Is there a work around ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Surely the `nittle()` function can refer to its own variables directly. Function-scope variables aren't going to be added by other code the way global variables can be.

Comment: @undefined I cannot do that. Its dynamic.Yes, I know that why i'm asking this question. 

nnnnn No It cannot.

Comment: @Jessica - How so? I mean why can't code in `nittle()` access its local variables. Any examples
?

Comment: @techfoobar becouse of `eval()`. I'm just simplifying it for the question.

Comment: `eval()` (if you must use it) if it helps, works *in scope*. For example: `eval('Pen')` from inside the function will return the value of `Pen`.

Comment: @techfoobar Please explain.

Comment: @Jessica - Check if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/mEjCf/

Comment: @techfoobar This is extremely convenient. WOW. But how would i go about without knowing "Pen" or potentially any other variable an just return all the entries that are instances of Dot?

Comment: Well, you can keep account of an instantiated `Dot`s and enumerate them.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mEjCf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to determine programmatically what variables have been declared inside a function, except perhaps to use `nittle.toString()` and then attempting to parse it yourself to find all the variables. <s>Maybe that could work for you? (But it's too messy for me to attempt here.)</s> UPDATE: but if the variables are created via `eval()` it won't work, you'd just see the `eval()` statement in the function's string representation.

> *Is there a work around ?*

You could declare a single object in your function and change all the variables into properties of that object:

```
function nittle() {
  var nittleVars = {
     var1 : "something",
     Pen : new Dot(),
     etc : "whatever"
  };

  for (var key in nittleVars){
    if( nittleVars[key] instanceof Dot ){
        alert("found it");
    }
  }
}
```

Your update indicates the variables are created with `eval()` - you could still do that with the object properties idea:

```
  eval("nittleVars.newVar = new Dot()");  // inside the function
```